# I want to multiply between two arrays values in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 2 Array called A and B, and I want to multiply 2 array values and create a new result array

```
  final a = <int>[2, 3, 4];
  final b = <int>[1, 2, 3];
          
  final result = <int>[2, 6, 12];
```

Please help me to achieve this thing in the flutter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I multiply two lists in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70612498/how-do-i-multiply-two-lists-in-flutter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
void main() {
      final a = <int>[2, 3, 4];
      final b = <int>[1, 2, 3];
    
      final result = <int>[];
    
      for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        result.add(a[i] * b[i]);
      }
    
      print(result);
    }
```